# POST-Request with QT5

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, http-post

I'm new to Qt and have some difficulties regarding a post request to a PHP file and reading the response.

Everything I found about how to implement a POST request in Qt 5 is somehow outdated (Qt 4.x) and does not work properly, OR doesn't help me because of some lack of knowledge.

For example, the php file looks like this:

```
<?php
     // read param1
     $value = $_POST['param1'];

     // Do some stuff here

     // return some text
     echo $value;
?>
```

All I want to do is this:

- Make a post-request and deliver some data (param1, value1)
- Read the return-value of the PHP file

Is there a small example of c++-code, how to implement this task with QT5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you try `QNetworkAccessManager`?

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

manager->post(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://example.com/yourscript.php")), data);
```

`data` is a `QByteArray` that you can generate from a QString if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked!     For completion: I used this to send the data:
    ----------
    QByteArray data;
    QUrlQuery params;
    params.addQueryItem("param1", "value1");
    params.addQueryItem("param2", "value2");
    params.addQueryItem("param3", "value3");
    data.append(params.toString());
    ----------
    This works very fine now, thanks again!